# Nano SQL dumping all changes into a "LOG" file, clogging up storage

Tags: sql, node.js, nano-sql

I am using Nano SQL for a social-media like service, but all upsert changes I make to the database is dumped in a log file.

The database folder is made up of other folders, each with a log file. Each time I upsert (edit) an entry, it appends some data to some of the log files.
For example, when I upvote a post, it appends this to the log file in the folder named `c1f7-5985`.

```
{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1,2],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,87905,278,3958713036
```

Problem is, this is for every single edit. If you were to spam upvotes... it would turn bad.

```
{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,86393,276,2301727765{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1,2],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,86695,278,314972973{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,86998,276,3245656695{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1,2],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,87300,278,1128401056{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,87604,276,941315798{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1,2],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,87905,278,3958713036{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,88209,276,2960535573{"id":1,"text":"Example post: Cheese is great!","creator":1,"created":1646028431162,"likes":[1,2],"repliesLastID":1,"replies":[{"id":0,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]},{"id":1,"author":2,"text":"Dude, I know! Cheese is amazzzing.","likes":[]}]}:1,1,88511,278,2923840566
```

This also is similar for other log files, such as the ones in `_ai_store` and `bea7-bc27`.

Some other unnecessarily bloated log files include `_utils`, `8061-c16a`, and `7b2c-ccd8`.

How I handle upvotes is similar to this:

```
return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  nSQL("posts").query("select").where(["id", "=", postId]).exec().then((r)=>{
    if(r.length == 1){
     if(r[0].likes.includes(creatorId)){
        r[0].likes = r[0].likes.filter(item => item !== creatorId)
        nSQL("posts").query("upsert",r).where(["id", "=", postId]).exec().then(res(-1)).catch(rej)
      }else{
        r[0].likes.push(creatorId)
        nSQL("posts").query("upsert",r).where(["id", "=", postId]).exec().then(res(1)).catch(rej)
      }
    }else{
      rej()
    }
  }).catch(rej)
})
```

Other functions are similar to this, mainly just doing something like

```
nSQL("posts").query("upsert",r).where(["id", "=", postId]).exec().then(res(1)).catch(rej)
```

to upsert the updated post/user.

**How can I cut down on the bloat in the log files?**

Update: I'm migrating everything to Sequelize. Answers on this post are still appreciated (especially for anyone else that may have this issue in the future), and you'll still get the 50 rep.

Comment: What underlying data store are you using?

Comment: @NickBailey I'm using Nano-SQL in "PERM" mode